# How to save DataTable Column Reorder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using [ColReorder](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/colreorder/)

In my javascript Column Reorder are set in this way:

```
 var table = $('#CardsGrid_grid').DataTable();
 new $.fn.dataTable.ColReorder(table);
```

Column reorder works fine but I still have an issue.
When I'm refreshing page, or returning to it from another one, **each column change are returned to original** so I need to move colums again. Basically, any column move lives till any kind of page refresh.

Is there a way to somehow store those changes? (While current session is still active).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at state saving: https://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/ColReorder/examples/state_save.html

It's as simple as adding the option to your initialisation:

```
var table = $('#CardsGrid_grid').DataTable({
    stateSave: true
});
new $.fn.dataTable.ColReorder(table);
```

Comment: Hm... looks simple but... how I supposed to call it? I tried add this but I received error: Cannet reinitialise DataTable, so... Is there a way to put this in my example?

Comment: I've updated my answer with what I think I would do. I'm not sure what you've tried though.

Comment: Managed to deal with it different way but still thanks (I totally forgot that my main initialisation are happening in another place):D. One more question. When I exit from the site, I am droping session. I log in, but now, all changes that I made for comuns are saved no matter what. It is... ok, I guess? State save is saved in browser cashe?

Comment: You'd have to check either their docs or the source. I couldn't tell you offhand.

Comment: Their state saving solution isn't really the best implementation imo, you cant save user presets in session storage, if they switch devices or clear cache then what?